# future.get does not work using java future/promise

Tags: java, playframework

I have something like this for making sendDate async using future

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
final Future<String> future = es.submit(new Callable<String>() {
    public String call() throws Exception {

         // SEND DATA return string
        return sendData(jObject.toString(), "delivery", act_id);
    }
});
System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n no future!" + future.get()); 
//then I tried to call it here
```

But I got an Error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: No EntityManager bound to this thread. Try
wrapping this call in JPA.withTransaction, or ensure that the HTTP
context is setup on this thread.
```

I'm very new to use promise/future and I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually says what you need to do in the error message :-)

Wrap the call to `sendData` method into a `JPA.withTransaction` call. This could look like this :

```
JPA.withTransaction(new play.libs.F.Function0<String>() {
    public String apply() {       
        return sendData(jObject.toString(), "delivery", act_id);
    }
});
```

Alternatively you can try to bind the EntityManager to the current thread using `ThreadLocal`.